# PyQTGraph ImageExporter bug related to image size

Tags: python, export, png, pyqtgraph

I am using pyqtgraph to produce plots in a PyQT window.
I want to export PNG image of the graphs.

I have this error when I try to export my plots:

> ImageExporter.py", line 70, in export
>      bg = np.empty((self.params['width'], self.params['height'], 4), >dtype=np.ubyte)
>   TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I noticed that the self.params['width'] and self.params['height'] are floats. But np.empty can not create an erray using float sizes.

Even if i set the width and height manually using :

```
exporter.parameters()['width'] = self.raw_DataPlot.width()
exporter.parameters()['height'] = self.raw_DataPlot.height()
```

The results are floats.

I noticed that If I change the line 70 of ImageExporter.py to :

```
bg = np.empty((int(self.params['width']), int(self.params['height']), 4),dtype=np.ubyte)
```

The export works fine.

Is it possible to address this issue and update the library?
Or is there a workaround that doesn't push me to change the pyqtgraph library itself.

Thanks

Comment: Report the bug.

Comment: I did report the issue on github's issues board. I was hoping for a workaround while waiting the update.

Comment: what you point out in your question is the workaround :)

Comment: It is not an elegant workaround since I did make a change in the library itself. When I send my code to someone else, the code does not work for him.

Comment: it does not say that it is elegant, but it is the only one that there is, upload your change to github, pypi, etc and then you indicate that they install it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I created a new ImageExporter that I integrated to my project.
I called this exporter PQG_ImageExporter so that we don't get confused.

I signaled this problem on github. I hope they fix it soon. When the problem will be solved, I can get back to the classic ImageExporter :

```
from pyqtgraph.exporters import Exporter
from pyqtgraph.parametertree import Parameter
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg, USE_PYSIDE
from pyqtgraph import functions as fn
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

__all__ = ['PQG_ImageExporter']


class PQG_ImageExporter(Exporter):
    Name = "Image File (PNG, TIF, JPG, ...)"
    allowCopy = True

    def __init__(self, item):
        Exporter.__init__(self, item)
        tr = self.getTargetRect()
        if isinstance(item, QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
            scene = item.scene()
        else:
            scene = item
        # scene.views()[0].backgroundBrush()
        bgbrush = pg.mkBrush('w')
        bg = bgbrush.color()
        if bgbrush.style() == QtCore.Qt.NoBrush:
            bg.setAlpha(0)

        self.params = Parameter(name='params', type='group', children=[
            {'name': 'width', 'type': 'int',
                'value': tr.width(), 'limits': (0, None)},
            {'name': 'height', 'type': 'int',
                'value': tr.height(), 'limits': (0, None)},
            {'name': 'antialias', 'type': 'bool', 'value': True},
            {'name': 'background', 'type': 'color', 'value': bg},
        ])
        self.params.param('width').sigValueChanged.connect(self.widthChanged)
        self.params.param('height').sigValueChanged.connect(self.heightChanged)

    def widthChanged(self):
        sr = self.getSourceRect()
        ar = float(sr.height()) / sr.width()
        self.params.param('height').setValue(
            self.params['width'] * ar, blockSignal=self.heightChanged)

    def heightChanged(self):
        sr = self.getSourceRect()
        ar = float(sr.width()) / sr.height()
        self.params.param('width').setValue(
            self.params['height'] * ar, blockSignal=self.widthChanged)

    def parameters(self):
        return self.params

    def export(self, fileName=None, toBytes=False, copy=False):
        if fileName is None and not toBytes and not copy:
            if USE_PYSIDE:
                filter = ["*."+str(f)
                          for f in QtGui.QImageWriter.supportedImageFormats()]
            else:
                filter = ["*."+bytes(f).decode('utf-8')
                          for f in QtGui.QImageWriter.supportedImageFormats()]
            preferred = ['*.png', '*.tif', '*.jpg']
            for p in preferred[::-1]:
                if p in filter:
                    filter.remove(p)
                    filter.insert(0, p)
            self.fileSaveDialog(filter=filter)
            return

        targetRect = QtCore.QRect(
            0, 0, self.params['width'], self.params['height'])
        sourceRect = self.getSourceRect()

        #self.png = QtGui.QImage(targetRect.size(), QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        # self.png.fill(pyqtgraph.mkColor(self.params['background']))
        w, h = self.params['width'], self.params['height']
        if w == 0 or h == 0:
            raise Exception(
                "Cannot export image with size=0 (requested export size is %dx%d)" % (w, h))
        bg = np.empty((int(self.params['width']), int(
            self.params['height']), 4), dtype=np.ubyte)
        color = self.params['background']
        bg[:, :, 0] = color.blue()
        bg[:, :, 1] = color.green()
        bg[:, :, 2] = color.red()
        bg[:, :, 3] = color.alpha()
        self.png = fn.makeQImage(bg, alpha=True)

        # set resolution of image:
        origTargetRect = self.getTargetRect()
        resolutionScale = targetRect.width() / origTargetRect.width()
        #self.png.setDotsPerMeterX(self.png.dotsPerMeterX() * resolutionScale)
        #self.png.setDotsPerMeterY(self.png.dotsPerMeterY() * resolutionScale)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.png)
        #dtr = painter.deviceTransform()
        try:
            self.setExportMode(True, {
                               'antialias': self.params['antialias'], 'background': self.params['background'], 'painter': painter, 'resolutionScale': resolutionScale})
            painter.setRenderHint(
                QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, self.params['antialias'])
            self.getScene().render(painter, QtCore.QRectF(
                targetRect), QtCore.QRectF(sourceRect))
        finally:
            self.setExportMode(False)
        painter.end()

        if copy:
            QtGui.QApplication.clipboard().setImage(self.png)
        elif toBytes:
            return self.png
        else:
            self.png.save(fileName)


PQG_ImageExporter.register()
```